# Group by dates using a different table date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to get the sum of costs by date, if the date lies between the start and end date which is coming in from a different table.
To explain:

Table 1

| id | date | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | $10 |
| 2 | 2020-03-05 | $100 |
| 1 | 2020-03-10 | $200 |
| 3 | 2020-07-16 | $200 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 | $50 |
| 1 | 2019-02-10 | $50 |
| 3 | 2012-10-01 | $500 |

Table 2

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-11-15 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-01-31 |

I just want to aggregate the costs by month only if the date in table 1 lies within the start and end date of table 2. So here I want the output to look like:

| date | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | $10 |
| 2020-02-29 | $10 |
| 2020-03-31 | $300 |
| 2020-04-30 | - |
| 2020-05-31 | - |
| 2020-06-30 | - |
| 2020-07-31 | $200 |
| 2020-08-31 | - |
| 2019-09-30 | - |
| 2019-10-31 | $500 |
| 2019-11-30 | - |
| 2019-12-31 | - |

What I have tried so far:

```
select sum(cost), last_day(date)
from table1 inner join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
and  table1.date>=table2.start_date  and  table1.date<=table2.end_date
group by last_day(date)
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: There are no 2019 and 2012 records in Table2 so why is 2019 in output with 2012 data?

Comment: Will need a dataset of all possible month end dates to join the query to if you want to show a record for each month even if there is no data.

Comment: And why is February aggregate repeated in January?

Comment: @June7 It's an option, but it's not a necessity (unless we define 'dataset' very loosely)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  year(date) as year,month(date) AS month, sum(cost) AS cost
from table1 inner join table2
on table1.id=table2.id
and  table1.date>=table2.start_date  and  table1.date<=table2.end_date
group by table1.id, year(date), month(date)
order by last_day(date)
```

Comment: I think need to group by last_day(date) not id.

Comment: Try both and see what fits your need.

Comment: Yes, I tried, although because I am in Access, had to use a different function to get the last day of month. I get the desired output.

Comment: I forgot the year/month , so I correct my answer and let you use the right function to get the last day with these 2 values if your really need this.

Comment: Essentially, query posted in question is correct. Again, including ID in grouping does not produce correct output. I am not the original poster. I am just reviewing your answer. So last_day() was appropriate, just not ID in grouping.

Comment: How you can sum by month if you group by last date with multi months duration?

Comment: Did you try without ID? Again, I get the result indicated by question. Read additional comments under question.

Comment: I try nothing, just read your question and your data, and how you can sum by month if you group by last date with multi months duration?

Comment: Again, not my question and not my data. I am a reviewer. I don't know how you infer aggregation for 'multiple months duration'. Question says wants to **aggregate the costs by month only if the date in table 1 lies within the start and end date**. Look at the output sample. Only July data shows in July aggregate. March aggregate includes two ID's.

Comment: 1) Start = 2020-01-01  End = 2020-12-31 -> 12 months

Comment: 2) My agregate is by month and of course year to cover different years.

Comment: 4 and last for 'today') Explain if you don't want to agregate by id 4.1) why there are duplicate id in table 1 4.2) How do you select the period (start , end) from table 2 versus the rows in table 1?